# Calculating single electron transfer

Tags: computational-chemistry, ab-initio-calculations, electronic-structure, molecular-modeling, reaction-mechanism

I'm thinking about doing some computational research about pyrazoline oxidation in chlorinated solvents under light. I've found plausible mechanism ([article](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tetlet.2019.07.023)) that involves single electron transfer from the molecule of pyrazoline to dichloroethane (DCE).

[image: Pyrazoline oxydation mechanism]

My main concern is about the second step, as there is electron transfer and change in multiplicity. I'm thinking about broken-symmetry DFT or multi-rerference methods, but I have no experience in them, so I'm not sure about it. What are the approaches to model such types of reactions? (I assume it has something to do with Marcus theory)

Comment: +1 But what is it that you want to model? The energy at each step of this sequence of reactions? The speed of each step? The probability that each step will occur? The nature of the wavefunction from step-to-step?

Comment: If you are interested in learning about calculating rates of electrons transfer, check out this [webinar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S6oSqh7KSR8) on constrained DFT.

Comment: @NikeDattani, let's say I want to have energy profile for entire reaction and transition states for each step. I'm not sure really, but I think it will help me to see how the substituents influence the reaction.

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/3983/24) can get some light.

Comment: @Camps thank you a lot, it really helps to understand the idea. I'm concerned about the change of multiplicity and initial photo excitation of the pyrazoline molecule, maybe it would be singlet-triplet transition and I need to account for it somehow.

Comment: Any update with this? Did you figure out the answer? Are you still working on it? Please update us!